# putting batch file errors and output to log file when executing batch through a perl script

Tags: perl, batch-file, call

I am new to perl.
I am executing a set of batch files in a perl script. I need to send the output(print statements and errors) of the batch file to a log file. The same log file that will have the output of my perl script. 
I have found many ways to put the output of the perl script to a log file but the output of the batch process that is called from the perl script is still not going to the logs.

My script looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path;
use File::Copy;
.
.
Print "abc";
.
my @args= ('C:\SBS\Install\UpgradeSBSDB_Oracle.bat');
open (FHU,"|@args") or die "Fail to open Upgrade.batch file: $!";
print FHU "\n";
.
.
Print " xyz";
.
.
```

The output in log looks like
abc
xyz

I also need the output of the batch file called in the logs

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your system call with backticks:

```
my $output =  `'C:\SBS\Install\UpgradeSBSDB_Oracle.bat`;
print FHU $output."\n";
```